# Unable to read messages from HornetQ queue in springboot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jms, hornetq

I am trying to setting up consumer with springboot but getting a difficulty. I have seen an example configuration of JMS Consumer setup and did the same but somehow consumer is not setting up properly and on Jconsole Queue is showing 0 consumer. Here is my springboot setup:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MongoConfiguration {
@Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        final Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("host", tcpServerURL);
        properties.put("port", tcpServerPort);
        final org.hornetq.api.core.TransportConfiguration configuration =
                new org.hornetq.api.core.TransportConfiguration("org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory", properties);
        return new org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQJMSConnectionFactory(false, configuration);
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);

        return factory;
    }
}
```

listener with queue destination

```
  @Component
    public class TrackerJmsListener {
        @JmsListener(destination = "trackerRec",containerFactory = "myFactory")
        public void handleMessage(String message) {//implicit message type conversion
            System.out.println("received: " + message);
        }
    }
```

Here is a jconsole of local running hornetq Mbean
[image]

I am confuse as there is no error showing on console and nothing is reading by consumer. If i change jms port or queue name then after starting of springboot app i see error message on console so my basic configuration seems to be right.

Basic setup of hornetq in server.

hornetq-configuration.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hornetq /schema/hornetq-configuration.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:hornetq">
    <connectors>
        <connector name="netty-connector">
            <factory-class>org.hornetq.integration.transports.netty.NettyConnectorFactory
            </factory-class>
        </connector>
    </connectors>
    <acceptors>
        <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">
            <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyAcceptorFactory
            </factory-class>
        </acceptor>
    </acceptors>
    <security-enabled>false</security-enabled>
</configuration>
```

hornetq-jms.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hornetq /schema/hornetq-jms.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:hornetq">
    <!--the connection factory used by the example -->
    <connection-factory name="ConnectionFactory">
        <connectors>
            <connector-ref connector-name="netty-connector" />
        </connectors>
        <entries>
            <entry name="ConnectionFactory" />
        </entries>
        <consumer-window-size>0</consumer-window-size>
        <connection-ttl>-1</connection-ttl>
    </connection-factory>
    <queue name="trackerRec">
        <entry name="trackerRec" />
    </queue>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JConsole screenshot is showing the attributes for the `trackerRec` *core* queue. However, that is not the core queue which corresponds with the `trackerRec` JMS queue which your application will be using. You need to look at the `jms.queue.trackerRec` core queue or look at the `trackerRec` JMS queue in the `JMS` tree.

Also, it's worth noting that the HornetQ code-base was donated to the Apache ActiveMQ project over three years ago now and that code-base lives on as the [Apache ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/artemis) broker. I **strongly** encourage you to move from HornetQ to ActiveMQ Artemis. There's been a ton of improvements, new features, bug fixes, etc. since the last HornetQ release. Also, since ActiveMQ Artemis 2.0 there is no longer an arbitrary separation between core addresses & queues and JMS queues & topics. The addressing model is more intuitive and powerful.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Yes i am also thinking to move into ActiveMQ as HornetQ is very old and not very easy to find a solution in case of any problem. My only reason to integrate HornetQ was to use it to run as standalone in inside of my application. I hope ActiveMQ also supporting this feature.

Comment: ActiveMQ Artemis can be embedded into any Java application just like HornetQ.

Comment: Perfect.. I will look into it. Thanks :)